# hide input after click button

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

my code

```
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $id = $row['id'];
       ?>
        <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#btn<?echo $id?>").click(function(){
                $("#inp<?echo $id?>").hide();
            });
        });
        </script>
        <?
           echo "<button id='btn$id' class='label label-info'>Dodaj odpowiedź</button>";?>
                    <div class="odpowiedz"><input id="inp<?echo $id;?>"></div>
```

my problem is that when i click the button function do nothing

@edit example html code after generate

```
$(document).ready(function(){
            $("#btn274").click(function(){
                $("#inp274").hide();
            });
        });
<button id="btn274" class="label label-info">Dodaj odpowiedź</button>
<div class="odpowiedz"><input id="inp274"></div>
```

Comment: surprise .. you can make a js code separatly  without repeating and putting it that way in php

Comment: that not fixing my problem man

Comment: you want (document).ready() call n times :P

Comment: Please include the generated HTML and JavaScript.

Comment: If the problem is in the generated client-side code, *show the generated client-side code*.

Comment: @Doknes: Works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/51ds2yre/

Comment: David i dont know how ,_,

Comment: @Doknes: Well, unless you can show code which actually demonstrates the problem, there isn't much we can do to help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use this outside php .. use it after include Jquery and before `</body>`

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('body').on('click',"[id^='btn']",function(){
           var getId = $(this).attr('id').replace('btn', '');
           $("#inp"+getId).hide();
        });
    });
</script>
```

and you can use [concatenate in php](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php)

```
echo "<button id='btn".$id."' class='label label-info'>Dodaj odpowiedź</button>
      <div class='odpowiedz'><input id='inp".$id."'></div>";
```

Answer (score 1):

if you want to hide <strike>button</strike> input  on click button simple JS

**Update**

```js
function callMe(obj) {
  obj.style.display = "none";
}
```

```html
<input id="sds" />
<button id="sds1" onclick="callMe(sds)">Submit10</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove javascript from your loop, better yet, put it in some javascript file

```
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $id = $row['id']; ?>


    <button id='btn<?=$id?>' class='label label-info'>Dodaj odpowiedź</button>
    <div class="odpowiedz"><input id="inp<?=$id?>"></div>

<? } ?>
```

And do what Mohamed-Yousef said:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('body').on('click',"[id^='btn']",function(){
    var getId = $(this).attr('id').replace('btn', '');
    $("#inp"+getId).hide();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <button id='btnapple' class='label label-info'>Dodaj odpowiedź</button>
    <div class="odpowiedz"><input id="inpapple"></div>

    
    <button id='btnbanana' class='label label-info'>Dodaj odpowiedź</button>
    <div class="odpowiedz"><input id="inpbanana"></div>

    
    <button id='btnorange' class='label label-info'>Dodaj odpowiedź</button>
    <div class="odpowiedz"><input id="inporange"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

To simply answer the question, the reason your specific example isn't working is that the script comes before the element it is meant to affect.

Turn `<script></script><button></button><input />` into `<button></button><input /><script></script>`

That being said, try to remove this to an external JS file and add a more generic method like what is suggested in other answers here. @Endless has a good solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you are having to output the same code to the page n number of times, then there is ALWAYS a better way. If you want to use jquery, use data attributes and classes:

```
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $id = $row['id'];
        echo "<button id='btn$id' class='label label-info toggle' data toggle="inp$id">Dodaj odpowiedź</button>";?>
       <div class="odpowiedz"><input id="inp<?echo $id;?>"></div>
}
```

Then your javascript is:

```
$(function(){
    $('toggle').click(function(){
        var id = $(this).data('toggle');
        $('#' + id).hide();
    });
});
```

Many buttons, many inputs, 1 javascript function to rule them all.